# Removal of Human Voice from a video or audio file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, adobe, video-processing

Is there a way by which i can remove the human voice from a audio/video. So ultimately the music is left on it.

I want to do this using any software like adobe etc or with command line like ffmpeg/sox.

But i prefer command line for tuning up the settings easily.

Comment: Refer to the [`equalizer`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#equalizer) or perhaps the [`bandreject`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#bandreject) audio filters if you want to try `ffmpeg`.

Comment: https://bandlab.com/splitter

Answer (score 6):

I've been working with karaoke for a while. There is no way to reliably remove vocal from the song which would result in acceptable quality music.

There are certain ways to do it, the most popular relying on a fact that the voice is usually center-panned to both channels while most of the instruments are not. You can use, for example, [Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/vocal_remover.html) to do that. It works well on some (but not all) songs as long as it is stereo, but the result music quality would hardly be acceptable in most cases, for two reasons:

- It will remove **everything** center-panned, such as kick drums (which are always center-panned), some other drums, and even some instruments which are center-panned (piano, for example, often is) - so the result music would sound kinda dull.
- It will not remove the voice completely as every recording adds some echo which is not fully center-panned, and it will still be there.

And this is NOT how the karaoke songs are created. They're created either by a musician band "in style of", or on computer. Neither makes sense if you need a popular song, as Amazon or karaoke-versions most likely would have it, and for 99c a song it won't worth an effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try ffmpeg you can do this by using [aergistal's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29210622/17011606) which removes center-panned audio:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=-1*c1" -ac 1 karaoke.mp3
```