# convert mp3 to mp3 karaoke with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need you to help me. I have tried several ways but does not work. I try to convert an mp3 file to karaoke with `ffmpeg`.

I tried this but does not work:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -af "highpass=f=120, lowpass=f=120, \
channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[L][R]; \
[R] biquad=-1:0:0:1:0:0[Rinv];[L][Rinv]amerge"  karaoke.mp3'
```

Comment: "does not work" is not helpful information. What is the actual issue? What exactly are you trying to do? You should always include the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Sorry, what I need is to remove or cancel the singer's voice in the musics using ffmpeg. Normally investing one of the channels can cancel the voice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use phase cancellation on a stereo track with centered vocals you can simply do:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=-1*c1" -ac 1 karaoke.mp3
```

As you can see `pan` also accepts a negative value.

Comment: this is great.  would it be possible to remove the music and keep the voice following the same idea?