# Remove human voice from audio/video with software or command line

Tags: audio, video

I'm seeking a way to remove a human voice from a video. Initially, I had the following:

- video1.mp4
- voice1.mp3

*video1* has images and only no-human-voice sounds while *voice1* has only one human voice Then I combined *video1* with *voice1* to create *video2.m4*, so in *video2* I can hear both audios from *video1* and from *voice1*. It is worth to mention that both *video1* and *voice1* have the same length of about 2 minutes.

This was one year ago. I deleted *video1.mp4* accidentally, but I still have *video2* and *voice1.*. Now I need to get *video1.mp4* again. In other words, **how to remove voice1 from video2?** How to remove the human voice from *video2*?

I don't care if this is through software, command line, or even computer code (maybe Phyton; I've heard that Python can do cool stuff with audio).

Note: there is a similar question here in StackOverflow ([Removal of Human Voice from a video or audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694377/removal-of-human-voice-from-a-video-or-audio-file)), but it doesn't explain how to remove the audio.

Comment: You could invert the voice audio and add it into video2.mp4. If the voice1 audio was not changed in any way when added to video 1, it should cancel out.

Comment: That’s not removal of human voice of course, but rather just simple [phase cancellation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference)

Comment: With respect to software, whatever you used to combine the audio and video in the first place should be able to: 1. invert voice1. 2. add the inverted voice1 file into video2

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you post it as an answer with a link of how to do a phase cancellation? That would be heplful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

Rather than thinking about this as a problem of removing an unwanted voice, I would think of this as simply undoing the sum of two signals. At the moment we have three audio signals to consider, lets call them

- `A`: The audio track to *video1.mp4*
- `B`: The audio of *voice1.mp3*
- `C`: The sum of `A` and `B` (i.e. `C = A + B`) which is now the audio track to `video2.mp4`

We no longer have access to `A`, but we still have `B` and `C`.

### The ideal case

The ideal case assumes:

- `A` is the same length as `B`
- Summing of the two signals was done without any filtering

#### Solution

The solution in this case is fairly trivial, all we need to do is multiply `B` by a gain value of `-1` (i.e. invert) and sum that with the signal `C`.

**if**

```
C = A + B
```

**then**

```
A = C - B
A = C + (B * -1)
```

Given you summed these signals in the first place, I assume you have access to some audio/video editing software. To invert `B` you could import the file into one of the following:

- [Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html)
- [Garage Band](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-invert-a-track-in-garageband)
- [FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/a/1066693)
- [Adobe Premier / Audition](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/audition/using/inverting-reversing-silencing-audio.html)
- [Final Cut Pro](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4141264)

Any software that can edit audio should also be capable of inverting audio signals. It would probably be ideal to have `C` and `B` in the same project for whatever [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) you are using to make tweaks on the fly.

#### Caveats

- If the gain of `B` was changed (i.e. `C = A + xB`), then the solution is still fairly trivial as you just multiply `-B` by a factor `x`
- If `B` is not the same length as `A` you will need to align `-B` with `C` correctly in order for the signals to cancel.

### The non-ideal case

If you consider there has been some process applied to `B` the solution is a little more involved. This process could be anything, filtering (EQ), delay, reverb, pitch shift, speed-shift. Lets call this process a function `H()` and if `B` is the input to that process then that is: `H(B)`.

**i.e**

```
C = A + H(B)
```

We can on longer simply invert `B`, we need to now apply exactly the same process to `B` first, then invert as `H(B)` may not be equal to `H(-B)`. You should process `B` in exactly the same way first and then invert it at the end.

If for whatever reason you can't remember the process applied to `B`, then that leaves you a little stuck. Your best bet in that case is to try and re-create the process with trial an error. There is likely to be some remnant of `H(B)` unless you match the process exactly.